# Inherit backbone attributes from parent model

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js

If i have this model:

```
var myParentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults:{ parent1: null,
              parent2: null}
)};
```

and i have another model:

```
var myModel = myParentModel.extend({
   defaults: {child1: null,
              child2: null}
)};
```

if i instanciate a new myModel:

```
var mymodel = new myModel({child1: 'mychild1'});
```

In the attributes property i only have set to default the child2 property, how is the implementation to inherit the parents property of the parent model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In github there is an [interesting post](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/476) with this issue, the solution that i was implement is this:

```
myModel.prototype.defaults = 
    _.extend({
        child1: null,
                child2: null
    }, myParentModel.prototype.defaults, 
       myModel.prototype.defaults);
```

With the underscore function: extend, we have a new object defaults with the parent and child prototype, this is a good solution for multiple inherit

Answer (score 2):

I used this, at this point there is not need to use prototype if you are in the same scope:

```
var abstractDefaults = {
  parent1 : '',
  parent2 : ''
};
var MyParentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults: abstractDefaults 
});
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults: _.extend( abstractDefaults, {
     child1 : '',
     child2 : ''
   } ) 
}); 
console.log(new MyModel().toJSON());
```

Comment: if you have more than one child model, the later child will inherit properties of earlier child, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend to use a function to extend the default attributes like this:

```
var MyParentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        parent1 : '',
        parent2 : ''
    }
});
var MyModel = MyParentModel.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return _.extend(
            {
                child1 : '',
                child2 : ''
            },
            MyParentModel.prototype.defaults
        );
    }
});
```

The reason is that you will avoid some troubles with a shared reference to the new default attributes between your different instances of the `MyModel` object

To make it clearer, if your default attributes contains array and if you instantiate your `MyModel` more than once, the attributes which contains the array will be shared between each instances. Using a function to declare your default attributes will avoid it.

I hope I'm clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ES6 destructuring

```
const MyParentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    parent1 : '',
    parent2 : ''
  }
});

const MyModel = MyParentModel.extend({
  defaults: {
    child1: '',
    child2: '',
    ...MyParentModel.prototype.defaults
  }
});
```